# serveResource called when i call actions

Tags: jquery, jakarta-ee, tomcat, liferay, portlet

i use jQuery.ajax to call this method in my portlet :

```
 serveResource(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response)
```

The problem is when i try to call any **action(ActionRequest req,ActionResponse resp)** or submit buttons,only **serveResource** is called .

To call serveResource i use  in my jsp :

```
 <portlet:resourceURL  var="ajaxURL" >
        <portlet:param name="jsp" value="<%=request.getPathInfo()%>" />
 </portlet:resourceURL>
```

Why only and always this method is called when i call an other actions methods .

EDIT:

My Controller Code:

```
public class ConseillerPorlet extends MVCPortlet {

public void addConsultant(ActionRequest request,ActionResponse response){
    List<String> errors=new ArrayList<String>();
        ConseillerLocalServiceUtil.addConseiller(request, response);

            SessionErrors.add(request, "error-saving-consultant");
            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    } 
@Override
     public void serveResource(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response) throws IOException, PortletException {
    String jsp=ParamUtil.getString(request, "jsp");
    System.out.println("ServeResouce Called by "+jsp);
    if(jsp.equals("/html/view.jsp")){
        String s="";
        List<Classe> classes;
        long Id=ParamUtil.getLong(request, "id");
        try {
            classes=Utils.getListClasses(etablissementId);
            for(Classe classe : classes)
            {
            s=s+"<option  value='"+classe.getClasseId()+"'>"+classe.getNomClasse()+"</option>";
            }
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
                response.getWriter().write(s);//return options for my <select> that i get using ajax and jquery  
    }
}
```

}

Thanks for help

Comment: It would be useful to see the rest of your controller code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had conflicts with id's because i used same javascript ajax function in two portlets without using
`<portlet:namespace />`

Answer (score 4):

It is because you're creating a resource URL and doing so will always hit the `serveResource` method. If you would like to hit action method you'll need to create an action URL.

```
<portlet:actionURL name="updateSomething" var="updateSomethingURL" />
```

Then inside your portlet class you can define:

```
public void updateSomething(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse)
    throws Exception {

    // Code goes here.
}
```

Note that the `name` attribute of `<portlet:actionURL />` corresponds to the method name above if you're extending the Liferay `MVCPortlet` class.

Comment: Yes this is what i do , for methods that are actions , i use actionURL with the name of method in my MVCPortlet. The problem is that when i call action using the submit buttons and action=my action URL ,only serveressouce is executed.I need ajax because i would like to get from the serveressouce some html data

Comment: In the code you've provided, you have created a `<portlet:resourceURL>` it needs to be `<portlet:actionURL>` in order for it to hit a method with an ActionRequest.

Comment: I don't want to hit it with an ActionRequest,i would like to hit it using onchange on a dropdown list.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the only option. The only other way if you'd like to use a resource url is to explicitly check and call your own method in `serveResource`.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @ rp solution...
You can also try this -

liferay-portlet:actionURL name="updateSomething" var="updateSomethingURL"

HTH